# glPush/PopMatrix() and glRotatef() seem to be moving objects individually instead of all objects contained within glPush/PopMatrix()

Tags: c++, opengl

I only started using OpenGL and C++ yesterday so it's likely I've just missed something, but it appears to me that code that should behave in exactly the same way just doesn't.

I have a few nested `glPush/PopMatrix()` functions which I'm using to animate some cylinders into a basic version of the Pixar lamp. What I want to do is rotate then about the point of the cylinder they're on top of, but that only seems to happen with the base cylinder and the one on top of that, go any higher and they just seem to move about a different axis.

I think I didn't explain that properly so I've added some images beneath my code.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(g_translate_x, g_translate_y, 0.0);
glRotatef(g_dof3_angle, 1, 0, 0);

    //base cylinder
    glPushMatrix();
    draw_bigcylinder(0, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(g_dof4_angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        //body cylinder
        glPushMatrix();
        draw_cylinder(0, 0, 90);
        glRotatef(g_dof5_angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


            //neck cylinder
            glPushMatrix();
            draw_cylinder(0, 9, 45);
            glRotatef(g_dof6_angle+90, 0, 1.0, 0);
            glTranslatef(0, 16, 4);

                glPushMatrix();
                gluCylinder(qobj, 2, 4, 7, 16, 16);

                glPopMatrix();

            glPopMatrix();

        glPopMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();
glPopMatrix();
```

[image: OpenGL Lamp]

Edit: here is the `draw_cylinder()` function:

void draw_cylinder(float translate_x, float translate_y, float dof3_angle){

```
    GLUquadricObj * qobj = gluNewQuadric();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(translate_x, translate_y, 0.0);
    glRotatef(dof3_angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(90, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        gluCylinder(qobj, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0, 16, 16);
        gluQuadricOrientation(qobj, GLU_INSIDE);
        gluDisk(qobj, 0.0, 1.0, 16, 16);
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 10.0);
        gluQuadricOrientation(qobj, GLU_OUTSIDE);
        glPopMatrix();

    glPopMatrix();
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code of your "draw_cylinder" method?

Comment: @redsoxfantom just edited it in now

Comment: @redsoxfantom I should probably also say that `draw_bigcylinder()` is exactly the same except for the parameters of `gluCylinder()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate your frame of reference to top of second cylinder. 
For this after you create your second cylinder do a `pushMatrix` then in that frame of reference translate again to center of cylinder (translate by half length of third cylinder). Create you cylinder there again and do a `popMatrix`. Now you will come to your original frame of reference in which you want rotate third cylinder. Put your rotate function on top of this push/pop block.